# Thinking of switching to Ubuntu!

Tags: system-installation

Will Ubuntu completely remove all my driver data? Will I have to re-download all of my Nvidia graphics drivers and even my wireless drivers? Will I be able to connect to the internet right away to do so even though I have completely replaced Windows 7?

Comment: You can test Ubuntu without installing anything... Burn it to a CD or USB (see the download pages' sidebars). That should answer your "will I be able to connect to the internet" question which is seemingly quite unique to each wireless chipset.

Comment: Drivers are generally not like in Win. The driver is part of the kernel so supported hardware just works. There can, however, be issues with differences between open-source vs proprietary drivers. This _might_ be an issue with your Nvidia card. If you have switchable graphics with optimus, search the site for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

***Q: Will Ubuntu completely remove all my driver data?***

A: Yes. They are not of much use under Ubuntu, as in general Windows programs (and drivers) don't work in Ubuntu. Note, If you choose to remove Windows, the installation will also remove all the partitions, such as `D:\` and any data, music, photos, videos, etc. **So make backups in an external media, before you proceed.**

***Will I have to re-download all of my Nvidia graphics drivers and even my wireless drivers?***

A: May be. There are two kinds of drivers, (1) open source, and (2) proprietary. If your Nvidia card and WiFi chip has open-source drivers, it is already included in the Linux kernel. In that case, you don't need to download anything. If your hardware needs proprietary drivers, you will be able to **check a box during installation** to download any drivers the may be needed.

The best course of action is to boot from a LiveDVD/USB and choose **"Try Ubuntu without installing."** If everything works, you can install without worries.

If something like WiFi does not work, confirm that Ethernet works and keep the computer connected to the Internet during installation. This will allow the installation process to look for updated drivers. Some WiFi chips may not have updated drivers in the repositories and you may have to manually download and install it. Search for chip specific instructions if this happens.

***Will I be able to connect to the internet right away to do so even though I have completely replaced Windows 7?***

A: Most probably you will either with WiFi or with wired Ethernet cable, or both. Verify by "Try without installing." Note, when you try Ubuntu from LiveDVD/USB, it may use either open-source or proprietary drivers. It is best to check the two options to (1) download updates and (2) install proprietary drivers, at the time of installation.

If your computer has Nvidia Optimus technology that seamlessly switches between two video cards, this won't work under Ubuntu. There are some tweaks to disable one of the cards you may want to search for after the installation is complete.

Hope this helps